# MySQL - Calculated row over many columns

Tags: mysql

This is a strategic question initially, not a debugging question. I'm also fairly new to sql in general, so there could be an easy answer I'm missing.

I have a largish table of historical data - 200,000+ rows (and growing rapidly) and 300+ columns. Each row contains time stamped data for the size of an object, each column represents one object.

I would like to compare the most recent 2 rows (time stamps) to detect a change - either positive, negative or no change.

Each row is created at 2 second intervals, so I need a query that is efficient enough to finish with time to take action on the comparison.

I have a few options:

- use `ORDER BY [DATETIME] DESC LIMIT 2` then transpose and use a generated column, however, this takes 3+ seconds.
- Re-write my earlier code to split my tables - one storing historical data and a much smaller one for transactional data.

I'm trying to avoid the latter option - Are there any other options?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Show create table output:
I can't find an elegant way to paste the code here - the formatting makes it hard to read. - Please accept this image.

[Show create table output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFCZi.png)

RE: Data sample - the data is just a 200,000 x 300 table full of numbers - refer below.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdcUi.png)

Comment: 3+ seconds seems very wrong.  Add output of `show create table yourtable` and your query and `explain` for your query.

Comment: This question is tagged `mysql`, but the bracket notation in your ORDER BY suggests SQL Server. Can you please clarify which RDBMS is implicated?

Comment: Adding examlpe data could help. This is very vague

Comment: The code notation here uses backticks, so my column definition (which also uses backticks) broke it... I substituted back ticks with brackets... 

show create table output is too long so I've truncated.
edit: refer original post.

Comment: A table with that many columns is an indication that it's a bad table design. What is the value in each of the column from 1 to 300 represent? Also the timestamp doesn't seem to match with _"Each row is created at 2 second intervals."_

Comment: Each column represents an object. one column per object. I'm not sure how to reduce the number of column without omitting objects.

Good observation on the time stamps - the initial dataset (in the screenshot) is at 5 second intervals (typically). The 2 second interval is planning ahead for higher resolution and to set an upper limit to the desired query performance.

Comment: Does your table have any index? If it have, is your query using it?

Comment: By the way, I'm tempted to suggest the second option that you're considering but replacing columns `1-300` with just two columns; for example `object_id` and `object_value`. This way, your comparison query **might** be a lot shorter. I'm not sure how you compare 2 rows but I think with 300 columns, it might look something like `SELECT timestamp, (row1)1 - (row2)1, (row1)2 - (row2)2 ... ` all the way to 300, maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: No explicit index - the time stamp column implicitly does that job.

Comment: Based on the responses, there isn't anything obvious that I'm missing (for example, NewRow = Row(x-1) - Row(x)), so it's just a matter of conditioning the data into a usable format, then solving. I'm using Node.js to condition and populate this table - to shorten a long story, I've think I've decided to keep it all in Node.js and populate a (new) table with the results only.

Comment: *"Based on the responses, there isn't anything obvious that I'm missing"* I think you missed the (obviously not obvious enough) hint from FaNo_FN that you need an index on the datetime column, which would bring the 3+ seconds you need for "ORDER BY [DATETIME] DESC LIMIT 2" down to 3+ ms.

Comment: Also, I am not entirely sure what you need as an end result - if you want to compare the complete table (e.g. each row to the previous row), and if you are on MySQL 8, you may want to use window functions (where you can do something like "look up the value of column x from the previous row" (but it also requires an index to be fast). But at least at first sight, you seem to only want to evaluate the (one) last row. You may want to clarify this.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE mytab ADD INDEX so68138852 (\`DATETIME\`)` ?